emission lighting render not right
I have rendered my image using denoising but when it finished the light sources seem to have this cross look too it which is not the intent. I just want a simple glow, all they have are emission nodes plugged into the surface and are at levels above 100 for the emission. I've also lowered the strength of emission, but nothing changes. 
the result I want is just a simple glow from parts that are bright. I want to share the file too but can figure that out. for now I have but what all of the objects have for their lighting.


You have already asked this question yesterday but deleted it. Please do not ask the same question multiple times! I gave tips in the comments and asked for some details, but you did not answer. Please show the emission material setup and the Compositor nodetree and follow my tips from yesterday for improvement.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
